# How does one make a [list].append function with input() [PYTHON 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have this code:

```
def add(whatlist):
    inf = True
    while inf == True and str(whatlist) in lists:
        addtol = input('What do you want to add to list {0}? Type in STOP_ to end this process.: '.format(whatlist))
        if addtol.upper() != 'STOP_':
            whatlist.append(addtol)
        else:
            inf = False
```

When I input a list, the interpreter says:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How could I make it so `input()` does not make my input a string?

Comment: either your whatlist object is a string or you need to convert input to a string by `addtol = str(input())`

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `add` function? And how is the `lists` variable defined?

Comment: can you mention the values for `whatlist` and `lists` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are doing a few things wrong here. First of all, `whatList` seems to be a string instead of list. So you might want to convert it into a list first. Once you fix that your `whatList` should start appending values into it. Also, there is some ambiguity on what `global lists` is doing. You might want to fix that as well. Also, once you get the input you can simply convert it into a string using `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval()` to make your string a list. `eval()` will work also, but it's not safe.

```
>>> import ast 
>>> a = '[1,2,3,4]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> type(ast.literal_eval(a))
<class 'list'>
```